# join and count occurrence

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm new to SQL and I have two tables like this

tab1:

```
+---+---+
| ID|som|
+---+---+
|  e|  1|
|  d|  j|
|  c|  1|
|  b|  1|
|  a|  p|
+---+---+
```

tab2:

```
+------+---+
|SK_CUR|som|
+------+---+
|     b|  d|
|     a|  c|
|     a|  i|
+------+---+
```

and I just want to count occurrence of letters in both tables. So the output should look like this:

```
+------+---+
|    ID| oc|
+------+---+
|     a|  3|
|     b|  2|
|     c|  1|
|     d|  1|
|     e|  1|
+------+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `union all` and `group by`:

```
select id, count(*)
from ((select id from t1) union all
      (select SK_CUR from t2)
     ) t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below query,

```
select ID , count(*) from (
select ID from tab1 where like '%[a-z]%'
union all
select som as ID from tab1 where som like '%[a-z]%'
union all
select SK_CUR as ID from tab2 where SK_CUR like '%[a-z]%'
union all
select som as ID from tab2 where som like '%[a-z]%')
group by ID
```

Since you need only letters from all the columns of both tables, i have used the filter 
like '%[a-z]%'